# access textbox from external class - get no errors

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, class, external

I have a project, designed with Visual Community 2015, based on Windows.Form.

I want to realized a simple Server program - using the msdn library:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

So I create a simple Form1 with the designer with a richTextbox (name: llog) and one button (click event pushthebutton), which called an external class AsynchronousSocketListener. after this, it should to be to call a methode logme() and a messagebox will pop-up (it works, I see this). But I cannot write into the richTextbox llog. I get no errors, but nothing is written into the box. I can remember, that it has something to do with the invoke or delegate problem. but I cant figure it out. I stuck here since 5 hours with no solution. Can anybody help me - what I have to do, to access the the box from the AsynchronousSocketListener() class? I dont know, why I get no errors!

You see my last attempt - I also try to parse the form as parameter on each methode call (nothing works) - but I cant believe, thats the right way...

ps: bad english, I know ...

```
// Form1.cs - I reduced it to the min - a window with a textbox and a button appears
namespace MyProject
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form {}


  public void pushthebutton() {
    AsynchronousSocketListener srv = new AsynchronousSocketListener();
        srv.StartListening();
  }

}



// AsynchronousSocketListener.cs
namespace MyProject
{
    public class AsynchronousSocketListener : Form1
    {
        // Thread signal.
        public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        public Form1 form;

        public AsynchronousSocketListener()
        {
            form = new Form1();
            logme(this, "constructer");
        }


        public void logme(Form1 form, string s)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("inside logme");

              if (llog.InvokeRequired)
              {
                  // invoke needed
                  form.llog.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { llog.AppendText("\r\n" + s); llog.ScrollToCaret(); });
              }
              else
              {
                  // no invoke needed
                  llog.AppendText("\r\n" + s);
                  llog.ScrollToCaret();
              }

        }
    }
}

// inside FormDesigner.cs - shortcut; box is public...
  public System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox llog;
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used winforms in forever, so I don't know whether or not this is a good practice, but in `AsynchronousSocketListener`, all you're doing is instantiating a new `form` that is not tied to anything.  You might want to actually pass your form into there

```
public AsynchronousSocketListener(Form1 parent)
{
    form = parent;
    logme(this, "constructer");
}
```

and in Form1

```
AsynchronousSocketListener srv = new AsynchronousSocketListener(this);
```

---

On a side note, I don't understand why `AsynchronousSocketListener` is inheriting from `Form1` as seen in the line `public class AsynchronousSocketListener : Form1`  that doesn't seem to be accomplishing anything

Comment: Thank you so much - this works for me - also for the hint for the inheriting Form1 makes no sense.I tried so many difficult ways to make this work, so now I deleted this assignment. At this time I have also problems to write into the textbox, because I got an error message (thread process cant write into the box - and I will figured it out later), but generally it works for me. Great!